# How to restore a retired app in wso2 emm?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I'm conducting a test with WSO2 EMM (v1.1.0).

How can I restore an app in the publisher of WSO2 EMM after it has been retired?
If it's not possible to "unretire", how can I completely delete the app so that I can add it again?

A related question is: Where are the apps stored (physically) on the server or in which database? (I have changed all databases from H2 to mysql, but can't find the database/table in which it is stored).

Comment: A not-so-elegant solution has been to create a new tenant. Unfortunately this leaves very little room for mistakes. You don't want to start a new tenant each time there is an app that has to be "unretired".

Comment: The related question is solved: info about the installed apps is stored in the database which is set up for the "Registry & User management". The app itself is stored in <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/upload.

Answer (score 0):

Retired app cannot be restored in EMM. However Deleting an app is possible in EMM 2.0 and above but not below versions.